# How do I specify an index for Elasticsearch using NEST?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

If I run the code below it will create a mapping on ALL indices, which I don't want.  I am unable to find the documentation for specifying just the index I want.
How do I specify which index to apply this mapping to?

```
var client = new ElasticClient();
var response = client.Map<Company>(m => m
    .Properties(props => props
        .Number(n => n
            .Name(p => p.ID)
            .Type(NumberType.Integer)
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `.Index()` to the put mapping descriptor

```
var response = client.Map<Company>(m => m
    .Index("index-name")
    .Properties(props => props
        .Number(n => n
            .Name(p => p.ID)
            .Type(NumberType.Integer)
        )
    )
);
```

This puts a mapping into an existing index. If an index doesn't yet exist, you can create it and define a mapping for it in one request. For example

```
var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex("index-name", c => c
    // settings for the index
    .Settings(s => s
        .NumberOfShards(3)
        .NumberOfReplicas(1)
        .RefreshInterval("5s")
    )
    // mappings for the index
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<Company>(mc => mc
            .Properties(props => props
                .Number(n => n
                    .Name(p => p.ID)
                    .Type(NumberType.Integer)
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this also will do.

```
        string IndexName = "my_index";
        this.client.CreateIndex(IndexName, c =>
            c.AddMapping<CForm>
            (m => m.Properties(ps => ps.Attachment
                                    (a => a.Name(o => o.Document)
                                           .TitleField(t => t.Name(x => x.Name)
                                                            .TermVector(TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets))))));


        // Create Mappings for the fields with specific properties.
        // You can also make field1 a multi-field and make it both analyzed and not_analyzed 
        // to get the best of both worlds (i.e. text matching on the analyzed field + aggregation on the exact value 
        // of the not_analyzed raw sub-field).

        // Field: Plan
        var result = this.client.Map<CForm>(m => m
             .Properties(props => props
                .MultiField(s => s
                    .Name(p => p.Plan)
                    .Fields(pprops => pprops
                                .String(ps => ps.Name(p => p.Plan).Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed))
                                .String(ps => ps.Name("original").Index(FieldIndexOption.Analyzed))
                        )
                     )
                 )
             );
```